# How I can avoid using `array_map` on my results returning primary keys in Laravel's 5.7 database layer?

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.7

I have the following table named `mytable`:

```
id SERIAL PK
namae VARCHAR
```

And using laravel **5.7** I need to retrieve the data using the following code (tested in a tinker session):

```
$yakuzaNames = DB::select('SELECT id from mytable where name like 'omaewa%');
dump($yakuzaNames);
```

The problem is that once data retrieved in variable `$yakuzaNames` is in the following format:

```
 [ { id: 1},{id:2},...]
```

From the results I need to retrieve an array containing integers with the id, therefore I need to manipulate it via `array_map`:

```
$yakuzaNames = DB::select('SELECT id from mytable where name like 'omaewa%');
$yakuzaNames = array_map(function($item){ return $item->id },$yakuzaNames);
```

Or use a foreach loop:

```
$yakuzaNames = DB::select('SELECT id from mytable where name like 'omaewa%');
$names = [];

foreach($yakuzaNames as $yakuzaName){
  $names[] = $yakuzaName->id;
}
```

But using a loop seems kinda a waste also using some sort of iteration seems waste as well. Is there a way for laravel's database layer be able to return directly the data in the format I want to?

Comment: I'd suggest to set a fetch mode for the query but I'm not a Laravel developer and I'm having a hard time finding the source code of the `select()` method (there are multiple uses of `__callStatic()`). If you know where it is I'd try to help more :)

Answer (score 2):

Use pluck method for collection. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: `select` returns an array instead of a collection. Therefore using the method `pluck` is not feasible.

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas You can convert array to collection. Or use query builder.